# How to find initial direction of an object using components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, velocity

I have a basic (not for me) physics question that I am struggling to get my head around. It involves a car moving at an unknown speed that explodes into 3 pieces. I am having trouble finding the original direction of the car and the speed of the car using the components I found.

Here is the circumstance under which this investigation occurs:

> Inspector Physics:  State your name please.
>
> Dannabelle Aeutscher:  Dannabelle Aeutscher
>
> Inspector Physics:  Ms Aeutscher, we are investigating the multiple
>   deaths of members of your high school physics class which occurred in
>   the suburb of Riverview, Queensland.  These persons were:  Daitlin
>   Cay, Nilliam Wgo, Coseph Jlarke, McEth Seill and Taymond Rurnbull.  Do
>   you understand?
>
> Dannabelle:  Yes.  I am only too willing to help you in your
>   investigation.
>
> Inspector Physics:  I am about to read to you the details of the
>   events that police have put together so far in the investigation.  You
>   are not required to say anything.  However, anything you do say may be
>   taken down and used as evidence in a court of law.  Do you understand?
>
> Dannabelle:  Yes.
>
> Inspector Physics:  On the afternoon of May 13th (Mother's Day), 2015
>   police were called to the scene of a car explosion.  You were seen
>   standing beside the crumpled remains of a section of car that had just
>   skidded to a halt.  You were interviewed by police at the scene of the
>   explosion and you told police that it was your car and you had been
>   driving at $60\,{\rm km}\,{\rm h}^{-1}$ when your car exploded into three pieces.  You
>   stated that through some miracle you managed to be still sitting in
>   one of these pieces that was ejected from the explosion and that this
>   piece of car had part of the tyre and breaking system still
>   functioning.  Furthermore, you managed to skid to a stop and get out
>   of the piece of wreckage with little more than a cut to your
>   right-hand pinkie finger.  Is this correct?
>
> Dannabelle:  Yes
>
> Inspector Physics:  From our initial investigations we have discovered
>   that the piece you were travelling in left a skid mark of $8.66 \,{\rm m}$
>   long and the coefficient of friction between the tyre and the road was
>   $0.7$.  However, the piece you were travelling in killed members of your Physics class Daitlin Cay, Nilliam Wgo, and Coseph Jlarke.  We have
>   determined that from the blast position, the first piece of wreckage
>   had a mass of $700\,{\rm kg}$ and headed north at a speed of $76.62\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}$.  The
>   second piece of wreckage of mass $400\,{\rm kg}$ headed ${\rm S}\,40^\circ\,{\rm W}$ at a speed of
>   $7.5\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}$.  The piece you were riding in had a mass of $500\,{\rm kg}$ and was heading in a direction ${\rm S}\,30^\circ\,{\rm E}$.
>
> Dannabelle:  Well, I am shocked and surprised at the death of my
>   classmates.  I was in the car trying to track down my stolen physics
>   book.  Someone from my physics class at St. Peter Claver had stolen it
>   and I was on my way to McEth Seill’s house to question him about it. 
>   However, I did not run down Daitlin, Nilliam, or Coseph with my piece
>   of car wreckage.  The evidence of the skid marks prove that I did try
>   to stop.

I have graphed and work out each component and know that the car was most likely traveling north at around $35\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1}$ but I can't figure out how to mathematically prove it.

All I need is a lead into how to find the initial direction and speed of the car.

Comment: Please show some details of your working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Having said this, you might consider calculating the total momentum immediately after the explosion. Remember that momentum is a vector.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, please consider stripping out the physically irrelevant narrative to focus on the *physics* problem only,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the work-energy theorem to find the speed of the fragment that you were travelling in after the collision.
Find the net momentum North and the net momentum West after the collision.
Find the magnitude of the momentum and its direction after the collision which will be the magnitude of the momentum and the direction of the car and occupants of mass 1600 kg before the collision.
Then you can find out whether or not the driver was speeding.

Comment: I got N 89 E Is this correct?

Comment: WTF farcher your wrong dick

Comment: Help me im dying

Comment: It is not 89 degrees East of North.  You have made a simple mistake.

Comment: I got it i think it's about 20 degrees North East am I right?

Comment: The 89 degree answer is almost correct.  Think about what you have written.

Comment: Did I mix up the 30 and 40 degrees it the components?

Comment: To put you out of your misery I think it is N01E.

Comment: Yes I got N1.9E when I changed the 30 and 40 degrees around however what us think?